# How to extract values from a dataframe based on dates?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a DataFrame (see image below) with daily values of which I want to retrieve a couple of values. I want to retrieve: Monthly mean, Monthly min, Monthly max, Yearly min, Amount of years etc. Currently I am resampling my DataFrame to retrieve these values (see code below) but there must be a better way.

[image: DataFrame]

```
 T_monthly=pd.DataFrame()                                                   # Create dataframe for monthly temperatures
 T_monthly['Basse']=temp_basse.iloc[:,3].resample("M").mean()               # Add Basse
 T_monthly['Basse_min']=temp_basse.iloc[:,3].resample("M").min()  
 T_monthly['Basse_max']=temp_basse.iloc[:,3].resample("M").max()  

 T_monthly['Kedougou']=temp_kedougou.iloc[:,3].resample("M").mean()         # Add Kedougou
 T_monthly['Kedougou_min']=temp_kedougou.iloc[:,3].resample("M").min()  
 T_monthly['Kedougou_max']=temp_kedougou.iloc[:,3].resample("M").max()  

 T_yearly=pd.DataFrame()                                                    # Create dataframe for yearly temperatures
 T_yearly['Basse_min']=temp_basse.iloc[:,3].resample("Y").min()  
 T_yearly['Basse_max']=temp_basse.iloc[:,3].resample("Y").max()
 T_yearly['Kedougou_min']=temp_kedougou.iloc[:,3].resample("Y").min()  
 T_yearly['Kedougou_max']=temp_kedougou.iloc[:,3].resample("Y").max()
```

Preferably I want to have a function where I can put in a date, e.g. 2014, 2 (Y, M) and retrieve all the necessary values without resampling to new DataFrames. For example:

> input: (2014, 2)
>
> output: [monthly mean, monthly min, monthly max, yearly min, yearly max]

At the moment my functions make use of the index number of the dataframes (see below). However, if I want to put in a certain date I first need to find the corresponding index number.

```
 T_monthly.iloc[i, 3]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `my_df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(my_df['date']).month`    =>  this will give new column `month` in my df `my_df`

Comment: After which you can filter by whichever month you want to .  example  - `my_df[my_df['month'] == 3]`  will give rows where `month==3` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added two more columns after the sugestion of Sowjanya R Bhat, containing ['year'] and ['month']

```
 df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).year
 df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).month
```

Next selecting data by:

```
 df.loc[(df['year'] == year) & (df['month'] == month)].iloc[:,3]
```

Not exactly how I wanted it (based on index), but great for looping through the data with the functions I wrote.